# What happens when a process tries to read more bytes than the one that sent it

Tags: sockets

If Two processes communicate via sockets and  Process A sends Process B 100 bytes.
Process B tries to read 150 bytes. Later Process A sends 50 bytes. 
What is the result of Process B's read?
Will the process B read wait until it receives 150 bytes?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what kind of socket it is.  For a STREAM socket, the read will return either the amount of data currently available or the amount requested (whichever is less) and will only ever block (wait) if there is no data available.

So in this example, assuming the 100 bytes have (all) been transmitted and received into the receive buffer when B reads from the socket and the additional 50 bytes have not yet been transmitted, the read will return those 100 bytes and will not wait.

Note also, the dependency of all the data being transmitted and received -- when process A writes data to a socket it will not necessarily be sent immediately or all at once.  Depending on the underlying transport, there's an MTU size and any write larger than that will be broken up.  Smaller writes may also be delayed and combined with later writes to make up the MTU.  So in your case the send of 100 bytes might be too large (and broken up), or might be too small and not be transmitted immediately.

Answer (score 0):

That is dependent on many factors, especially related to the type of socket, but also to the timing.

Generally, however, the receive buffer size is considered a maximum. So, if a process executes a `recv` with a buffer size of 150, but the operating system has only received 100 bytes so far from the peer socket, usually the available 100 are delivered to the receiving process (and the return value of the system call will reflect that). It is the responsibility of the receiving application to go back and execute `recv` again if it is expecting more data.

Another related factor (which will not generally be the case with a short transfer like 150 bytes but definitely will if you're sending a megabyte, say) is that the sender's apparently "atomic" `send` of 1000000 bytes will not all be *delivered* in one packet to the receiving peer, so if the receiver has a corresponding `recv` with a 1000000 byte buffer, it's *very unlikely* that all the data will be received in one call. Again, it's the receiver's responsibility to continue calling `recv` until it has received all the data sent.

And it's generally the responsibility of the sender and receiver to somehow coordinate what the expected size is. One common way to do so is by including a fixed-length header at the beginning of each logical transmission telling the receiver how many bytes are to be expected.